# Enable class constructor in some enumerated template cases

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

For performance reasons, I'm using a templated class with an enum instead of relay on inheritance (It is not an option).

At this point I have something like:

```
typedef enum { A, B, C, D } QueueType;

template <QueueType T> class Queue {
    Queue(int a){...} // only usable when T = A
    Queue(unsigned a, unsigned b){...} // only usable when T = B || T = C
    Queue(somestruct z){...} // only usable when T = B || T = C
    //other constructors
}
```

Now I'm using an annoying amount of ifs/switches over `T` and rising exceptions if an incompatible constructor is called for a defined `T`.

What I want is to use `std::enable_if` or equivalent to prevent throwing exceptions on constructor and detect on compilation time such kind of errors.

I've tried many stack-overflows and foreign sites `std::enable_if` examples, but I can barely understand what I'm really doing and I always end on a compilation error.

Thanks in advance and sorry for asking for a probably trivially answered question. I'm noob with templates.

**Environment**: Linux GCC 8 and c++14
**Restrictions**: Maximal performance with no virtual methods.

Comment: can you show one of your attempts together with the errors you get?

Comment: What about `Queue(int a, std::enable_if_t<T == A>* = nullptr){...} // only usable when T = A`   ??? Have you tried?

Comment: @PiotrNycz , not that exactly, as I've tried always to put it on the template not as parameter.

Comment: What's stopping you from using inheritance?  Because if it's only for the idea that somehow inheritance makes things slower, you may find that the compiler is smarter than you give it credit for.  Prefer to write things in a straightforward manner.  Your future self will thank you.

Comment: @AndreKostur I have to process packets in terms of millions per second. Each if/branch matters even how caches / branch predicions are made.
If you have to consider virtual methods and resolve them, it is simple too much in this case. Of course, it is not like inheritance is bad or something like that, more over, we use them in other places but at that critical performance point just a couple mermory access or branches can make us loss some gigabit/s/per core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I want is to use std::enable_if or equivalent to prevent throwing exceptions on constructor and detect on compilation time such kind of errors.
>
> I've tried many stack-overflows and foreign sites `std::enable_if` examples, but I can barely understand what I'm really doing and I always end on a compilation error.

The problem with `std::enable_if` (and SFINAE, more in general) is that it works only checking template parameters. So can enable/disable a full class, with a test over a template parameter of the class, but can't enable/disable a single method, with a test over a template parameter of the class.

If you want SFINAE enable/disable a method (like your constructors) you have to made it a template method and test a template parameter of the method itself.

So you can't write something as

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<T == A>>
Queue (int)
 { } // only usable when T = A
```

because `T` is a template parameter of the class, not of the constructor.

But there is a trick: you can use default values/types for template parameters; so the following code works

```
template <QueueType U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<U == A>>
Queue (int)
 { } // only usable when T = A
```

because is checked the value `U` that is a template parameter of the constructor.

To enable the second constructor only when `T` is `B` or `C`, you can write

```
template <QueueType U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<(U == B) || (U == C)>> 
Queue (unsigned, unsigned)
 { } // only usable when T = B || T = C
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef enum { A, B, C, D } QueueType;

template <QueueType T>
struct Queue
 {
   template <QueueType U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<U == A>>
   Queue (int)
    { } // only usable when T = A

   template <QueueType U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<(U == B) || (U == C)>>
   Queue (unsigned, unsigned)
    { } // only usable when T = B || T = C
 };

int main()
 {
   Queue<A>  qa0{1};         // compile
   //Queue<A>  qa1{1u, 2u};  // compilation error

   // Queue<B>  qb0{1};      // compilation error
   Queue<B>  qb1{1u, 2u};    // compile

   // Queue<C>  qc0{1};      // compilation error
   Queue<C>  qc1{1u, 2u};    // compile

   // Queue<D>  qd0{1};      // compilation error
   // Queue<D>  qd1{1u, 2u}; // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @max66. I finally get it working and I think I also understand how it does.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I'm using an annoying amount of ifs/switches over T and rising exceptions if an incompatible constructor is called for a defined T.

So it seems you don't need your constructor to be SFINAE friendly, so `static_assert` seems sufficient:

```
template <QueueType T>
class Queue {
public:
    Queue(int a)
    {
        static_assert(T == A, "!");
        // ...
    }
    Queue(unsigned a, unsigned b)
    {
        static_assert(T == B || T == C, "!");
        // ...
    }
    Queue(somestruct z)
    {
        static_assert(T == B || T == C, "!");
        // ...
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: But make sure to add a more useful error message than `"!"`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen compilers will typically show you the line with the error, hence imho in this particular case it is even better to not write a message

Comment: I agree no message is better than `"!"`, but I would write a message anyway. Otherwise, if someone uses the wrong constructor, they will get an error like `file.cc:123 error: static assertion failed: static_assert(T == A)`, which is not very helpful, especially if the person using the wrong constructor doesn't know anything about the internals of `class Queue`, and perhaps doesn't even know that it's a template. Some hint that a *different* constructor exists and must be used would be nice.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: C++11/C++14 requires a message, only since C++17 we can put no messages :-/. And I don't doubt that meaningful message can be added but I don't have relevant one here.

Answer (score 2):

Static asserts are fine - but you might delete these constructors for all enum values - except the one you want to provide:

```
template <QueueType T> 
class Queue 
{
public:    
    Queue(int a) = delete; // only usable when T = A
    //other constructors
    Queue(unsigned a, unsigned b) = delete; // only usable when T = B || T = C
    Queue(somestruct z) = delete; // only usable when T = B || T = C

private:
    // not necessary - but allows to have a little less code
    struct EnablerType {};
    static constexpr EnablerType Enabler{};
    Queue(unsigned a, unsigned b, EnablerType) { }// only usable when T = B || T = C
    Queue(somestruct z, EnablerType) { } // only usable when T = B || T = C

};
```

Now - explicit enabling:

```
template <>
inline Queue<A>::Queue(int a) {}
template <>
inline Queue<B>::Queue(unsigned a, unsigned b) : Queue(a, b, Enabler) {}
template <>
inline Queue<C>::Queue(unsigned a, unsigned b) : Queue(a, b, Enabler) {}
template <>
inline Queue<B>::Queue(somestruct z) : Queue(z, Enabler) {}
template <>
inline Queue<C>::Queue(somestruct z) : Queue(z, Enabler) {}
```

One big advantage over sulution with `static_assert` is that you can check if `Queue` is constructed from the given set of parameters (so you can make further SFINAE):

```
int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<Queue<A>, int>, "failed");
    static_assert(!std::is_constructible_v<Queue<B>, int>, "failed");
    ...
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Qoqqm8GiVSD19E1w)

Comment: The drawback is that the error message will be something like `error: use of deleted function ‘Queue<T>::Queue(int)'`. A `static_assert()` would allow a more helpful error message, and if the constructors were not deleted to begin with, the compiler (well, I only tested GCC here) would have listed possible other constructors.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I added one advantage over static_assert solution to my answer